# Dequeue message from exception queue

Tags: oracle

How to **dequeue** messages from **exception queue**?
I searched in google but did not get any idea in brief.

Comment: People ask questions here because of their technical issues. If you know the answer please answer it otherwise don't just vote on post negatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must start your exception queue:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE('OWNER.your_ex_q', true, true);
```

Then you can run the following instruction to dequeue, passing the MSG_ID:

```
DECLARE
   dequeue_options     dbms_aq.dequeue_options_t;
   message_properties  dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
   message_handle      RAW(16);
   message             aq.message_typ;

BEGIN
   DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(queue_name => 'msg_queue',
           dequeue_options    => dequeue_options,
           message_properties => message_properties,
           payload            => message,
           msgid              => message_handle);

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: If you like me getting ORA-24017 on START_QUEUE, change the second parameter to false, because it is not allowed to enqueue to exception queue

Answer (score 0):

If that's about Oracle Advanced Queuing (which I don't know), Google knows that Oracle says the following:

> **How do I dequeue from an exception queue?**
>
> The exception queue for a multiconsumer queue must also be a
>   multiconsumer queue.
>
> Expired messages in multiconsumer queues cannot be dequeued by the
>   intended recipients of the message. However, they can be dequeued in
>   the REMOVE mode once (only once) using a NULL consumer name in dequeue
>   options. Messages can also be dequeued from an exception queue by
>   specifying the message ID.
>
> Expired messages can be dequeued only by specifying message ID if the
>   multiconsumer exception queue was created in a queue table without the
>   compatible parameter or with the compatible parameter set to '8.0'

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I am aware of this. But I don't know how to do this practically. And thanks for your response.

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know, I've never used advanced queuing.